# How to get/find the element of text value in table? Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, html-table

I'm having trouble in finding the text value inside the table, here's the sample screenshot of the table.

When i try to get the firepath, it shows a dynamic id:

```
.//*[@id='UID18-33316107000078976-1444640760832Display']/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]
```

I need to get the exact Value inside the table example "3004". I tried using this xpath contains but still no luck.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(//td[contains(.,'3004')]));
```

is there a way to extract the value inside this tables? 
Heres the element of tables.

Note: Tried using FirePath for the highlighted element output is:

```
.//*[@id='tdDataDiv']
```

It's the same id for all selected rows. It doesn't seem to work also.

UPDATE: @alecxe

This is the error shown when i try using the .getText() on the xpath. So the problem is im having a null pointer when im getting the value of the element. the xpath you can be found, but i cannot get the text from the xpath.

Thanks for all those who will look into this. Please do notify me if more info needed thanks!

Comment: It's not the `<td>` which has the value, it's the `<div>` inside the `<td>`, which in this case has `id=tdDataDiv`. Since id's are supposed to be unique within a page, you can just use the following XPath: `//div[@id='tdDataDiv']`.

Comment: @t0mppa hmm yes i think you are correct but what i need to get is the value inside the id=tdDataDiv which is the "3004".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the `EMP_COMPANY` label beforehand:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(div, 'EMP_COMPANY')]/following-sibling::td/div[@id = 'tdDataDiv']")).getText();
```

Comment: element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(., 'EMP_COMPANY')]/following-sibling::td/div[@id = 'tdDataDiv']")).getText();  System.out.println(element)                                                                    <<<<<<  tried doing this and still having a null pointer.

Comment: @user3713453 okay, what error exactly do you get? (post an error traceback please)

Comment: I'm getting null pointer when im using the .getText(); method on the xpath you gave. But when i try finding the xpath it was successfully found. im just having trouble on getting the value inside that xpath.

Comment: @user3713453 I think the problem is definitely not in the XPath expression. Please post your complete traceback.

Comment: Yes I've added the whole class for you to check if i am missing something, driver is already defined on the top.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92092/discussion-between-user3713453-and-alecxe).

Comment: Hi @alexce what do you mean by it was never assigned.

Comment: Resolved the null pointer, was able to get the xpath of driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(., 'EMP_COMPANY')]/following-sibling::td/div[@id = 'tdDataDiv']")).. What i need to get now is the value 3004 in the table. Tried changing the EMP_COMPANY to 3004 and result was:  Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td[contains(., ' 3004 ')]/following-sibling::td/div[@id = 'tdDataDiv']"}

Comment: @user3713453 that's better. Can you expand all of the cells in this row and provide it's HTML representation? Thanks.

Comment: This is so weird.. I was still unable to locate text value 3004, driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(div, '3004')]/following-sibling::td/div[@id = 'tdDataDiv']")); When you look at their html its same with EMP_COMPANY.. hmmm i can find EMP_COMPANY but not 3004.. :(

Comment: @user3713453 can you just try to execute exactly the same XPath expression as in the answer? Thanks.

Comment: Executed the exact edited answer and it was able find the element but did not display any text value of '3004'..

Comment: tried also storing it to a string like this> String sCellValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(div, 'EMP_COMPANY')]/following-sibling::td/div[@id = 'tdDataDiv']")).getText();
   System.out.println(sCellValue); it just display a String output on console..

Comment: Finally got it working! thanks alecxe! driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[5]/following-sibling::td/div[@id = 'tdDataDiv']")).getText(); I removed the contains function and added a col number.